# Integrating SVNServer and Redmine

Tags: svn, redmine, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

Can someone help me to integrate Visual SVNServer and redmine over Windows Server 2003?
I want to do the same actions from Redmine as I can do from Tortoise connected to Visual SVN Server.
I tried to follow some WEB articles without success.
Thanks in Advance,

Jorge

Answer (score 1):

I have been recently successful in integrating Redmine, Visual SVNServer, Subversion and TortoiseSVN in the Windows environment. However, you need to be specific on what "actions" you want to integrate. Here's the level of integration I've been able to implement:

- When a user commits to the subversion repository with proper comments, the revision links to the issues(s)
- When a user commits to the subversion repository with proper comments, the issues(s) status change
- When a user commits to the subversion repository with proper comments, the issues(s) % done changes
- Redmine successfully browses subversion repository
- Redmine successfully performs diffs
- Some other goodies that I might be forgetting

List what you want to achieve and where you  have been able to go so far and I'll be able to help more.

Comment: If a tutorial exists for these things, a link to it would be helpful.

Comment: @RoyTinker there are some guides on Redmine's issue tracker and forums: https://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/48319